# Android unit testing content resolver class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test the following method in Android.  I have used Junit and Mockito.

How do I mock `contentResolver.delete` method?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried something but I get null pointer exception @MaciejKowalski

Comment: can you post your test code?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I just updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Dont think you need to use reflection here.

Try to

**1)** Set-up the mocked `ContentResolver`

**2)** Expect certain method called on `LauncherServerCallback`

```
@Test
public void testDeleteUser() throws Exception
{
    // Arrange
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
    Mockito.doReturn(1).when(contentResolver).delete(UserProvider.CONTENT_USER_URI, null, null);

    // Act
    launcher.deleteUser(contentResolver,launcherServerCallback);

   // Assert
   Mockito.verify(launcherServerCallback).onSuccess(Mockito.anyString());
}
```

You may also need to add this to kick-off the Mockito engine:

```
@Before
public void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

**Tip**: you shouldnt test private methods. So either try to increase the visibiilty or move that code into a separate class.

Comment: Null pointer exception is caught. Should we not add values before delete?

Comment: You have to inject the dependencies into launcher object. Or use @InjectMocks annotation